# Alarm Manager is running immediately

Tags: java, android

```
            Date dat = new Date();
            Calendar cal_alarm = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar cal_now = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal_alarm.setTime(dat);
            cal_alarm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hrs);// set the alarm time
            cal_alarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
            cal_alarm.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            cal_alarm.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            if (cal_alarm.before(cal_now)) {// if its in the past increment
                cal_alarm.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, AlarmReceiver.class);
            // intent.putExtra("Reminder to Take Photo", "Pixitch!");
            PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 0010000,
                    intent, 0);
            // Get the AlarmManager service
            long tmemills = cal_alarm.getTimeInMillis()
                    - cal_now.getTimeInMillis();
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, tmemills,
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, sender);
```

Alarm Receiver Class

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private NotificationManager notificationManager;
private Notification myNotification;

// Context ctx = this;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {
        NotificationManager mNM;
        mNM = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(
                R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Pixitch Notification !",
                System.currentTimeMillis());
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                new Intent(context, AlarmManage.class), 0);
        // Set the info for the views that show in the notification panel.
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Pixitch Notification!",
                "Reminder For TakePhoto", contentIntent);
        mNM.notify(0, notification);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(
                context,
                "There was an error somewhere, but we still received an alarm",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

}

the value of tmemills is 278,088

the tmemills is around 4.5 minutes but

the alarm Manager is Running immediately

I am not able to find where the problem is because I am beginner for Android. please help me

Comment: post ur AlarmReceiver.class

Comment: Dear @Indiandroid added Alarm Reciever class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, tmemills + System.currentTimeMillis(), 
     AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, sender);
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of `tmemills`. Use `cal_alarm.getTimeInMillis()` as the second parameter to your `set()` call on `AlarmManager`, as that is the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch at which you want the event to occur.